# Can't delete a folder even with sudo su

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root

I used the Ubuntu customization tool and the terminal stopped so I decided "Oh well, I'll just close it!". Now the 2 folders it made 'remaster-iso' and 'remaster-root' both have a lock sign on the folder picture. Remaster-root has a X sign on it as well as a lock. First I try to deal with remaster-iso. But it's owned by root. I can't delete it. I know no other thing (for example, if there was something like the windows built in administrator account i didn't know about). I tried all these terminal commands

```
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak# cd tmp/remaster-iso/
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/tmp/remaster-iso# rm -rf remaster-iso
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/tmp/remaster-iso# sudo su
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/tmp/remaster-iso# sudo su
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/tmp/remaster-iso# sudo rm -rf remaster-iso
root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/tmp/remaster-iso#
```

It will still not go away! I need a solution apart from a clean reinstall! I am outraged!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to delete the folder from within the folder itself and giving a non-existing path for rm to delete.

Do something like:

```
cd ~/tmp
sudo rm -rf remaster-iso
```

Comment: Do I need to use `sudo su`?

Comment: No, the commands posted above should be sufficient.